# Can't add SHA1 fingerprint to Firebase Console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm able to add a SHA1 fingerprint certificate in the Firebase Console under Project Settings / Android App, but as soon as I refresh the page (or navigate away and navigate back) it's gone. I'm having no problems with SHA256 certificates.

I need SHA1 certificates for passwordless sign in to work. Am I missing something?

[image: Adding SHA1 from debug keystore to Firebase Console]

Comment: If you're having a problem with the Firebase console, please contact Firebase support for help.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: Thanks! I just sent a support request. I'll update/delete this question as I get more information.

Comment: Recently I faced similar problem I couldn't add new app.

Comment: Just got a response from firebase support... it's an issue with the firebase console displaying recently added SHA1 certificates and hopefully will be fixed soon! The SHA1s are still being added though, even though they don't show up here. You can check that they exist under OAuth 2 Client IDs at this link: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=<your-firebase-project-name>

Comment: This was a bug with the firebase console and it's fixed now.

Comment: I had the same issue but I resolved it, the reason was I was copying little extra space with my sha1 key, by removing that space I resolved this error..

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. Just delete unwanted project. I found same SHA1 key in other project after delete them issue was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

[Credential in API console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=%3Cyour-firebase-project-name)
I had the same problem.
This link from the previous answers helped me to remove some of my older apps , i was exceeding the quto of 30 client ID's per project
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the [Credential in API Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=%3Cyour-firebase-project-name) really works. And Also after that don't forget to run Flutter Clean or you will continue to have the same error.